# Styling on font awesome in Angular

Tags: angular, font-awesome

Hello I am using **Font awesome 5** with **Angular 6**

```
<span><fa-icon [icon]="faSearch"></fa-icon></span>
```

But I'm not able to apply any `width` or `height` as it is `svg`.

Please help

Comment: Hello!
I believe using the size classes is the best way-
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/sizing-icons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use transform:scale(x,y) property to resize the svg (x ,y represents to what % it needs to be resized for eg 0.5 means 50%)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This is for the coffee icon. Similarly, you can do for the `fa-search` icon

```
::ng-deep .fa-coffee {
  width: 50px !important;
  height: 50px !important;
}
```

Inspect on the search icon and see the elements in the developer tools and find the css class and put it in the place of `.fa-coffee` from above. Mostly, it would be `fa-search`

Comment: Be careful, ngdeep is being deprecated - https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep